# Rails 5.2 - How to implement quantity availability check with cart booking app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

Im building a Golf Cart rental app where Users can Book Golf Carts, what I need help with is implementing a Quantity and Availability check where when a cart is booked, the quantity is subtracted by 1 UNTIL the booking end date, and if quantity is currently 0 the cart is considered unavailable and unbookable. Im using Rails 5.2,

I have a Devise User model with added first and last name. A Cart model with name, description, quantity, and price columns. And a Booking model with start date, end date, user_id and cart_id columns. A User has_many bookings, a cart has_many bookings, and a booking belongs_to User.

I've been trying it on my own for days and no answers on here take into account the quantity aspect that I'm looking for.

Comment: "Quantity" suggests multiple identical items without separate identity. You have a "Cart" model, suggesting you will have a database of individual carts each having a unique id. So I don't see how "quantity" would have anything to do with it. To determine availability, wouldn't you just look up a cart, look at its bookings, and determine if any booking encompasses the dates in question?

Comment: The Cart model has three records ie. cart types.  I want to add quantities to them and make those three available to book, if quantity is greater than 0 during the specified booking dates

Comment: My gut response to this is, "You're doing it wrong." Anytime I have three fixed records in a database table, I would ask myself, "Why is this not a data structure in memory?" Why not just allow Booking to have a "cart_type" column, and use Rails' nifty enum module to specify which cart type applies for each Booking?

Comment: okay, makes sense. how would I go about assigning prices and quantities to said enum values?

Comment: That's a separate question, and you should pose it as such. You can see one example of a similar implementation (but using string keys instead of enum) [here](https://github.com/SplitTime/OpenSplitTime/tree/master/app/services/results). Look at the `template.rb` and `templates.rb` files. You should probably run through some tutorials and play around with code and try things out so you can ask specific questions, which are the proper subject of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good example of a problem that could be solved either by computing values or by storing them in a database. I do not think you want to store "quantity" or "availability" in a database structure.

Per my comments, you should consider storing your "Carts" model (which I would rename "CartTypes") in memory. The only reason I can see to store it in a database table would be if you need to update the characteristics frequently--for example, if carts often break down and need to be fixed, you would need to change the total available carts for a given type.

In either case, you would have a "total_available" attribute for your CartType model. I would definitely not store a "quantity" attribute. Instead, you'll want to look at your bookings, determine the cart_type, start_date, and end_date, count the bookings for a particular cart_type on a given date, and subtract that number from total_available to determine availability.

How you write the query to do this depends on your schema and relationships. If you can be more specific, then I can provide a specific query.